# TextInput Layout with boundary

Tags: android, android-layout

So basically my idea is to create a Floating Label EditText with a boundary around it. 
The case is when the EditText is not in focus the hint should appear centre vertically, but when it is focused then it will expand inside.

I am attaching the examples as well : 
[image]

The upper one is the focused and the lower one is without focus.

Please help.

Edit the password Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/relativePsw"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="56dp"
  android:background="@drawable/psw_et_boundary">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_drawable"
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
            style="@style/EditTextCustomHolo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java :

Initially setting padding :

```
  mRelativePsw.setPadding(dpToPx(14), 0, dpToPx(14), 0);
  mPasswordEt.setPadding(0, dpToPx(10), 0, 0);
```

OnFocusChange :

```
  mPasswordEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focus) {
            if (focus) {
                mPasswordEt.setPadding(dpToPx(14), dpToPx((float) 6.3), dpToPx(14), 0);
                mRelativePsw.setPadding(0, dpToPx(12), 0, 0);
                Utils.showSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this, mPasswordEt);
            } else {
                if (mPasswordEt.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    mPasswordEt.setPadding(dpToPx(14), 0, dpToPx(14), 0);
                    mRelativePsw.setPadding(0, dpToPx(10), 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It is a lengthy process to handle every single one of them like this. So help is suggested.

Comment: put some code of your xml file? if u have

Comment: your idea is very interesting, what is your question then?

Comment: How to go about it.. I used one method in which i used to change the padding dynamically, it sort of works but is very lengthy to implement.
I'll attach the code too.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for this is that, add your border design drawable file to TextInputLayout as a background and set some padding to that approx 8dp will be proper. then set background of TextInputEditText as 
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

so default line of that edit text will be disappear and when focus on that edit text and when you will enter something in that then label will be inside that border.

try this code it is what you want label will be at center.

try this it's proper for that it gives floating label in the center.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: That's the thing.. the label is not in the centre then.

Comment: try this it's proper for that it gives floating label in the center.